# Convert array of strings to array of integer

Tags: php, arrays, type-conversion

I've got strange output from array_map with `intval` parameter.

```
$array = ['35','1'];


array_map('intval', $array);
```

Output:

> array(2) {   [0]=>   int(1)   [1]=>   int(1) }

and if I execute 
`array_map`

with **'curent'** parameter

```
array_map('curent', $array);
```

I've got

> array(2) {   [0]=>   string(2) "35"   [1]=>   string(1) "1" }

Comment: https://eval.in/654717 . you forgot to assign after `array_map()`

Comment: In most cases the answer would be: You don't need to, PHP does this automatically when needed.

However, you haven't said anything about why you're looking to do this. What is the end goal of having the the arrays converted to an integer, instead of having PHP do this automatically whenever it needs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example

```
$array = ['35','1'];
var_dump(array_map('intval', $array));
```

That will output the desired outcome.

Comment: I don't know why this don't work well in mu example, problem is because this not works fine. It always returns    (int) 1 for each array element.